Why yolov8 works and yolov8.2 does not
I have been working with a YOLO library for object detection. I encountered such a problem that when I had Yolo 8.2 installed and used the command :
yolo predict model=yolov8x.pt source='plane.jpg' save=true
then the results of aircraft object recognition were very unsatisfactory - dozens of classes were detected, but none of them pointed to an aircraft (photo),
failed aircraft recognition
and when I installed yolo 8.0.2 then the model did fine (photo):
successful aircraft recognition
Pip list when Yolo v8.2 is installed
Package                 Version
----------------------- --------------------
absl-py                 2.1.0
annotated-types         0.7.0
anyio                   4.4.0
asttokens               2.4.1
certifi                 2024.7.4
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
click                   8.1.7
colorama                0.4.6
coloredlogs             15.0.1
contourpy               1.2.1
cycler                  0.12.1
decorator               5.1.1
dnspython               2.6.1
email_validator         2.2.0
exceptiongroup          1.2.2
executing               2.0.1
fastapi                 0.111.1
fastapi-cli             0.0.4
filelock                3.15.4
flatbuffers             24.3.25
fonttools               4.53.1
fsspec                  2024.6.1
grpcio                  1.65.2
h11                     0.14.0
httpcore                1.0.5
httptools               0.6.1
httpx                   0.27.0
humanfriendly           10.0
idna                    3.7
ipython                 8.26.0
jedi                    0.19.1
Jinja2                  3.1.4
kiwisolver              1.4.5
Markdown                3.6
markdown-it-py          3.0.0
MarkupSafe              2.1.5
matplotlib              3.9.1
matplotlib-inline       0.1.7
mdurl                   0.1.2
mpmath                  1.3.0
networkx                3.3
numpy                   1.26.4
onnx                    1.16.1
onnxruntime             1.18.1
opencv-python           4.10.0.84
packaging               24.1
pandas                  2.2.2
parso                   0.8.4
pillow                  10.4.0
pip                     23.2.1
prompt_toolkit          3.0.47
protobuf                4.25.4
psutil                  6.0.0
pure_eval               0.2.3
py-cpuinfo              9.0.0
pydantic                2.8.2
pydantic_core           2.20.1
Pygments                2.18.0
pyparsing               3.1.2
pyreadline3             3.4.1
python-dateutil         2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv           1.0.1
python-multipart        0.0.9
pytz                    2024.1
PyYAML                  6.0.1
requests                2.32.3
rich                    13.7.1
scipy                   1.14.0
seaborn                 0.13.2
sentry-sdk              2.12.0
setuptools              68.2.0
shellingham             1.5.4
six                     1.16.0
sniffio                 1.3.1
stack-data              0.6.3
starlette               0.37.2
sympy                   1.13.1
tensorboard             2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
thop                    0.1.1.post2209072238
torch                   2.4.0
torchaudio              2.4.0
torchvision             0.19.0
tqdm                    4.66.4
traitlets               5.14.3
typer                   0.12.3
typing_extensions       4.12.2
tzdata                  2024.1
ultralytics             8.2.70
ultralytics-thop        2.0.0
urllib3                 2.2.2
uvicorn                 0.30.3
watchfiles              0.22.0
wcwidth                 0.2.13
websockets              12.0
Werkzeug                3.0.3
wheel                   0.41.2

Pip list when Yolo v8.0 is installed
absl-py                 2.1.0
annotated-types         0.7.0
anyio                   4.4.0
asttokens               2.4.1
certifi                 2024.7.4
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
click                   8.1.7
colorama                0.4.6
coloredlogs             15.0.1
contourpy               1.2.1
cycler                  0.12.1
decorator               5.1.1
dnspython               2.6.1
email_validator         2.2.0
exceptiongroup          1.2.2
executing               2.0.1
fastapi                 0.111.1
fastapi-cli             0.0.4
filelock                3.15.4
flatbuffers             24.3.25
fonttools               4.53.1
fsspec                  2024.6.1
grpcio                  1.65.2
h11                     0.14.0
httpcore                1.0.5
httptools               0.6.1
httpx                   0.27.0
humanfriendly           10.0
idna                    3.7
ipython                 8.26.0
jedi                    0.19.1
Jinja2                  3.1.4
kiwisolver              1.4.5
Markdown                3.6
markdown-it-py          3.0.0
MarkupSafe              2.1.5
matplotlib              3.9.1
matplotlib-inline       0.1.7
mdurl                   0.1.2
mpmath                  1.3.0
networkx                3.3
numpy                   1.26.4
onnx                    1.16.1
onnxruntime             1.18.1
opencv-python           4.10.0.84
packaging               24.1
pandas                  2.2.2
parso                   0.8.4
pillow                  10.4.0
pip                     23.2.1
prompt_toolkit          3.0.47
protobuf                4.25.4
psutil                  6.0.0
pure_eval               0.2.3
py-cpuinfo              9.0.0
pydantic                2.8.2
pydantic_core           2.20.1
Pygments                2.18.0
pyparsing               3.1.2
pyreadline3             3.4.1
python-dateutil         2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv           1.0.1
python-multipart        0.0.9
pytz                    2024.1
PyYAML                  6.0.1
requests                2.32.3
rich                    13.7.1
scipy                   1.14.0
seaborn                 0.13.2
sentry-sdk              2.12.0
setuptools              68.2.0
shellingham             1.5.4
six                     1.16.0
sniffio                 1.3.1
stack-data              0.6.3
starlette               0.37.2
sympy                   1.13.1
tensorboard             2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
thop                    0.1.1.post2209072238
torch                   2.4.0
torchaudio              2.4.0
torchvision             0.19.0
tqdm                    4.66.4
traitlets               5.14.3
typer                   0.12.3
typing_extensions       4.12.2
tzdata                  2024.1
ultralytics             8.0.20
ultralytics-thop        2.0.0
urllib3                 2.2.2
uvicorn                 0.30.3
watchfiles              0.22.0
wcwidth                 0.2.13
websockets              12.0
Werkzeug                3.0.3
wheel                   0.41.2

I deleted the old models each time before using the method, so that it downloads the new model to the actual version.
Can someone explain to me what the problem might be? Somehow I don't believe that the models that are uploaded on the main YOLO website are wrong.
